# How to omit filename from Emacs mode-line?

Tags: emacs

Because I use `path-headerline-mode` and small screen laptop, the filename on menubar (or menuline, at the bottom of the window) is not needed for my setup. How can I hide it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: maybe this fits better on [emacs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your init file:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format (remove 'mode-line-buffer-identification mode-line-format))
```

It is the presence of `mode-line-buffer-identification` in `mode-line-format` that causes the mode line to show the buffer name.

See the Elisp manual, node [Mode Line Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html) for more information.

Comment: Thx! And I did same on spacemacs via "spaceline-toggle-buffer-id-off".